# Tooltip css position adsolute in li

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I have a tooltip which I use with is JS and CSS
But when it is in an `<li>` it display to the left of the page, not next to the image, like it should.

Any ideas, it works fine when not in a `<li>`.
Below is the code

JS Code

```
this.showTooltip = function (a, b) {
    $("#" + b).css("left", $(a).position().left + 20 + "px");
    $("#" + b).css("top", $(a).position().top + "px");
    $("#" + b).fadeIn("slow")
};
this.hideTooltip = function (a) {
    $("#" + a).fadeOut("slow")
};
this.formSubmit = function (a) {
    $("#orderform")[0].submit()
};
this.mainPageShow = function (b, a) {
    $("#header_" + b).hide();
    $("#header_" + a).show()
}
```

CSS Code

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #dadada;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 200px;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<ul>
    <li><img onmouseover="showTooltip(this,'a');" onmouseout="hideTooltip('a');" alt="Tooltip" src="img/content/question.gif" width="20" height="20" align="left" />A</li>
    <li><img onmouseover="showTooltip(this,'b');" onmouseout="hideTooltip('b');" alt="Tooltip" src="img/content/question.gif" width="20" height="20" align="left" />B</li>
    <li><img onmouseover="showTooltip(this,'c');" onmouseout="hideTooltip('c');" alt="Tooltip" src="img/content/question.gif" width="20" height="20" align="left" />C</li>
</ul>

<div class="tooltip" id="a" style="display: none;">A test</div>
<div class="tooltip" id="b" style="display: none;">B test</div>
<div class="tooltip" id="c" style="display: none;">C test</div>
```

Comment: You're aware that absolute positioned elements are positioned relative to their [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetParent) element? I.e. to the closest element, which is not positioned static.

Comment: Despite my answer below, regarding your specific case, you should try using offset() instead position(). position() will only work well if your <li>/<img> elements are positioned absolutely or relatively, which is not the case.

Comment: offset did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply your logic, by removing inline JS code and so forth. Below is a working example.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-tooltip="Tooltip explanation for A"><span>Question A</span></li>
    <li data-tooltip="Tooltip explanation for B"><span>Question B</span></li>
    <li data-tooltip="Tooltip explanation for C"><span>Question C</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="tooltip" class="nd"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#tooltip {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
.nd {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var tooltip = $("#tooltip");
    $('[data-tooltip]').bind('mouseover', function() {
        var $this = $(this), offset = $this.offset(), posX = offset.left, posY = offset.top;
        posX += $this.find('span').innerWidth();
        tooltip.
            css({left: posX + "px", top: posY + "px"}).
            text($this.attr('data-tooltip')).
            removeClass("nd");
    }).bind('mouseout', function() { tooltip.addClass('nd'); });
});
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/4s9Uz/

As you can see. It's quite simple. There are some restrictions and observations regarding this approach:

- It work properly when the element is inside an element with overflow rule (where it has scrollable content).
- If the element is too far on right the tooltip will exceed the viewport and forcing the browser to show an horizontal scrollbar.
- In this case, you'll need to use span as I did, to make the tooltip appear right after the end of its content. It'll possibly not work well if the content in the span tag has multiple lines. But it should be confirmed.
- You'll just need elements with data-tooltip attribute in it, with the text you want to show. If you want to show anything beyond just text you'll need to improve this approach.

But at least you have something to being with and improve further.